# Application_Start() Called everytime if site don't be used in while

Tags: asp.net

I have asp.net web application. after I ran app the application_Start called.
if I hold a page and I reload (or postback) the page after the a few minute(about 10-15 minute) I lost the viewstate and sessionstate and application_Start called again.
if I open the site application_Start is called and if I close the browser and open the site again after a few minute(like above) application_Start called again.
its only happened on my host. but on localhost haven't face this problem.
it's a problem from my application or from host? how can I trace the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your application pool is being recycled. Read up [here](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/windowsserver2003/library/iis/1eee28e2-b319-4b4e-8267-a8c0aa0dcf36.mspx) for more information (for IIS6) or [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753179%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) (for IIS7).

Comment: Yes, this is normal behaviour. You may want to look at using state server session state instead of inproc. State server means that session is stored in another process, either on the same server or another server and and is not stored in the asp.net worker process i.e. If the app pool is recycled, you'll still have session state. Alternatively, you could use SQL server session state as Jonas suggests

Comment: It is normal, if your application doesn't receive any activity after a certain time, the process hosting it will terminate, causing any sessions to be lost. You can use SQL session state to get around that, or you can increase the duration your worker process will live.

Comment: @Russ Cam : Is there a way to change this behavior? or i should leave it this way?

Comment: @Raika - have a read of the articles that Jonas has linked to to see whether you want to change this behaviour or not. If you still have questions after that, then come back and update your question :)